# What's your experience with the AWS NAT Gateway performance?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, performance, nat

[In December/2015 Amazon launched their VPC NAT Gateway service](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/introducing-amazon-vpc-nat-gateway-a-managed-nat-service/) which is basically a managed alternative to creating your own (and [it looks very good in comparison to NAT instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-comparison.html)).

I was just about to deploy my own NAT instances and I decided to [use the NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) instead to save me the hassle of configuring and maintaining my own NAT service.

The service works as advertised and I've been a happy chappy until I noticed a strange behaviour.

I use EC2 instances behind the NAT gateway to test a bunch of websites, running up to 4 parallel Firefox+selenium tests per EC2 instance.  I noticed that tests that were previously running fine elsewhere had been failing on this environment.

So I spun-up 2x t2.large instances, one with a public elastic IP and direct access to the Internet; the other with a private IP, behind the NAT gateway.

Here are the results of running [apache benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) against some sites:

**EIP**

```
ab -kn 1000 -c 20 https://www.pinterest.com/
(...)
Time taken for tests:   17.331 seconds

ab -kn 1000 -c 20 http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db
(...)
Time taken for tests:   9.610 seconds

ab -kn 1000 -c 20 http://www.bbc.com/
(...)
Time taken for tests:   5.890 seconds
```

**NAT**

```
ab -kn 1000 -c 20 https://www.pinterest.com/
(...)
Time taken for tests:   25.980 seconds

ab -kn 1000 -c 20 http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db
(...)
Time taken for tests:   14.920 seconds

ab -kn 1000 -c 20 http://www.bbc.com/
(...)
Time taken for tests:   6.552 seconds
```

The server behind the NAT gateway is outperformed by the service with direct connection by a significant percentage in many cases.

AWS says that the service "Supports bursts of up to 10Gbps" which is more than what the individual instances I used can do.

I noticed that if I turn-off keep-alive (i.e. the `-k`) the performance becomes similar:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 20 https://www.pinterest.com/
EIP:   18.316 seconds
NAT:   17.763 seconds
```

What is this sorcery? What's going on? Are my benchmarks relevant?

What has been your experience?

Comment: I have just run some tests behind a NAT instance (t2.medium) and the results are similar to the one with direct access to the Internet. If my benchmarks and web site test results are anything to go by, the AWS NAT Gateway service is *NOT* ready for prime-time.

Answer (score 1):

My Nat gateway setup is fresh new and nothing custom.
Here is my result for command

```
siege -c 100 https://www.pinterest.com -v
```

with Nat gateway :

```
Transactions:              15012 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             140.40 secs
Data transferred:         335.43 MB
Response time:              0.43 secs
Transaction rate:         106.92 trans/sec
Throughput:             2.39 MB/sec
Concurrency:               46.39
Successful transactions:       15012
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            5.90
Shortest transaction:           0.29
```

without Nat Gateway

```
Transactions:              11519 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             107.02 secs
Data transferred:         257.20 MB
Response time:              0.43 secs
Transaction rate:         107.63 trans/sec
Throughput:             2.40 MB/sec
Concurrency:               46.33
Successful transactions:       11519
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            4.02
Shortest transaction:           0.28
```

Almost same.